# Where do i define topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm testing kafka a little, and hopefully am going to put it in my production stack soon. 
I'm using the files `kafka-console-producer.sh` and `kafka-console-consumer.sh` to test kafka's functionality.

I created a topic with 2 partitions, but I see that all the messages my producer is sending are going to one partition.

I searched this on the internet and read that there is a setting called `topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms` that tells the producer to change the partition it's currently writing to, and that the default is 10 min.

I'm trying to change this setting, but I don't understand where... ?

Comment: How did you find out that all messages were going to one partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka properties can be found in the following three files

**`server.properties, producer.properties, consumer.properties`**

These files will be available in the folder **`kafka-folder/config/`**. By default some properties will be available in those file. You can add what ever the properties you want. The list of properties is given in this link **https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html**. This link contains detail explanation of all the properties for server, producer and consumer.

Since **`topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms`** is a producer configuration, you need to add this property in the **`producer.properties`** file

Note the above link is the property configurations for the **kafka-0.8 version**.

Comment: If I want to set this property in python SimpleProducer, then how I can define?

Answer (score 2):

You can also set it up inside a [producer class](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms", "10");
ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you are referring to the Java client and Jaya's answer is sufficient. In case you are playing with the configuration of client built on top of `librdkafka` then the configuration can be slightly different:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

`metadata.max.age.ms`:
Metadata cache max age. Defaults to metadata.refresh.interval.ms * 3. Type: integer

`topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms`:
Topic metadata refresh interval in milliseconds. The metadata is automatically refreshed on error and connect. Use -1 to disable the intervalled refresh. Type: integer